# Air Ionizers built in to laptops - Marketing gimmick?

Tags: consumer-products

I came across this claim on a currently selling [Asus laptop](http://www.asus.com/Notebooks/Versatile_Performance/N51Vf/):

[image]

My gut reaction is that this is just a marketing gimmick.  Is there any way to validate Asus's claims?

Comment: It could be both...

Comment: How big/powerful is the fan?

Comment: @DVK: I have no idea; I don't own the laptop or have access to any other specs beside what is on the asus website.  It just struck me as a dubious claim.

Comment: The language around it is probably pure marketing. The ionizer itself is most likely there to reduce electrostatic discharge problems, a likely source of warranty replacement/repair costs (ionizers are standard fare in static-sensitive electronics workshops, along with bonding bracelets, dissipative mats, etc.). How do you sell an extra-cost add-in to consumers when the idea is to save *you* money over the long haul?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Air Ionizers are commonly used to clean particulates out of the air](http://web.bsu.edu/IEN/archives/2001/031501.htm).  However, in looking at this laptop and the language used in the advertising, I think there is a conflagration  of two separate goals.  The language used in the picture does indeed correspond to what an air ionizer *does*, however, the size limitations of the laptop may impact its ability to do so.  Instead, the more likely scenario is for this part to help protect the laptop itself from particulates, and the language preys on the gullibility of the customer.

[This paper](https://mospace.umsystem.edu/xmlui/bitstream/handle/10355/3595/AreAlternativeTherapiesEffective.pdf?sequence=1) states in it's fast track summary regarding asthma (emphasis mine)

> No evidence supports use of room **air ionizers**, homeopathy, or mind-body therapy for the treatment of asthma

So even though an air ionizer will trap electrostatically charged particles, it really has no benefit to people.  And that brings up the possibility of uncontrolled [ESD](http://snebulos.mit.edu/projects/reference/NASA-Generic/NASA-STD-8739-7.pdf) in the laptop.